# Explicit definition of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need to find an explicit definition for the recursive sequence
$$a_0=2,\space a_n=a_{n-1}*(2+4n)$$
My first instinct was to do something like $a_n=2(2+4n)^n$. However, that doesn't work because the common ratio *isn't* $2+4n$ where *n* is treated as a constant, it changes for each term, meaning the sequence looks like this:
$$2*(2+4)*(2+8)*(2+12)*(2+16)*\space...$$
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\prod_{n=1}^j\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=\prod_{n=1}^j(2+4n)=2^j\prod_{n=1}^j(2n+1)=2^j(2j+1)!!\\
\implies\frac{a_j}{a_0}=2^j(2j+1)!!\\
\implies a_j=2\frac{(2j+1)!}{j!}
$$